# Problems with returning json

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a function in `json` and in this function I call a controller passing a parameter of type string. And in this function I enter into the database and retrieve the desired information, so that´s okay. However my result doesn't show in this view. Returning an error and not the information wanted. Can someone help me?

**My code**

```
$('#btnPesquisarPaciente').click(function () {
    var nomePesquisado = $('#txtNomePaciente').val();
    if (nomePesquisado != '') {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "pacientes/recuperaPacientePorNome",
            data: { nomePaciente: nomePesquisado },
            success: function (data) {
                // console.log('nome encontrado' + data.NOME);
                $('#lblPaciente').text = 'fa';
                //var pacienteEncontrado = $('lblPaciente').html();
                //pacienteEncontrado.append($('<p/>').html('<b>' + paciente.NOME + '</b>'));
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('NÃO FOI POSSÍVEL ENCONTRAR ESTE PACIENTE');
            }
        })
    } else {
        alert('INFORME O NOME DO PACIENTE DESEJADO');
    }
})
```

**My controller**

```
public JsonResult recuperaPacientePorNome(string nomePaciente) {
    paciente p = null;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nomePaciente)) {
        using(db=new crm_webEntities()) {
           p = (from x in db.paciente where x.NOME.ToUpper().StartsWith(nomePaciente.ToUpper()) select x).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
    return Json(p, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: `$('#lblPaciente').text = 'fa';` should be `$('#lblPaciente').text('fa');` Ref. http://api.jquery.com/text/

Comment: well - share the error with us

Answer (score 0):

You need to stringify your data object in your ajax call:

```
data: "{ nomePaciente: nomePesquisado }"
```

Also you need to specify the contentType:

```
contentType: "application/json"
```

Please refer to jQuery Ajax reference (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings)

Comment: Json.stringify({nomePaciente : nomePesquisado }) : (unavailable)

Comment: `JSON.stringify()` it's case sensitive

Comment: Sorry, but dont work, I do not know what's happening.

Comment: You do not need to stringify the data, and since OP is making a GET, then doing so would not work anyway (a get has no body so setting `contentType: "application/json"` is pointless)

Comment: Well he's passing data so either a) change method to POST or b) remove data property and pass it as a qyerystring or index parameter in the url